# Openlayers 3 polygon-feature "collision"?

Tags: openlayers

I am currently building a webapp using openlayers 3.

I build in "GPS-tracking" as a features and I got some questions with that.
So, is it possible to run a function if a GPS-Position as a point-feature, reaches or "collides" with a polygon, which is drawn on the map?

E.g

```
if(positionFeature.getCoorinates() === polygon1.getCoordinates()){
   return "do someting";
} else { 
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose that you get the closest point of the polygon to your point, compute the distance and set the condition on that distance being smaller than a precision value ( which you define ) :

```
var wgs84sphere= new ol.Sphere(6378137);
var distance= wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(yourPolygon.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(yourPoint.getGeometry().getCoordinates()),yourPoint.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
if(distance<=yourValue){
     //do something
}
else{
     // something else
}
```

Comment: What Unit (Meters, Kilometers) is "yourValue"?

Comment: @jokey meters, you can always convert it to another unit

Comment: Thanks, how would this work for other projections (e.g CH1903+) without a sphere?

Comment: @jokey the only way I know to measure real distance with OL-3 is through the `ol.Sphere` , you can transform the projection of your geometries only when measuring them without applying that transformation on the renderning of the features and the map